# Import error when using uwsgi with django (Symbol not found: __PyInt_AsInt)

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

I've tried looking for a fix, but wasn't able to. Sorry if this question exists elsewhere.

I'm following http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html, and am currently trying to make sure django works with uWSGI. I'm trying to run `uWSGI --http-socket :8000 --module mysite.wsgi`, but am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mysite/wsgi.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 3, in <module>
    import cgi
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/cgi.py", line 50, in <module>
    import mimetools
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/mimetools.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 32, in <module>
    import io as _io
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
    import _io
ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyInt_AsInt
  Referenced from: /anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

I already had issues with uWSGI not using the right installation.`uwsgi` would try to use `/usr/local/bin/uwsgi` despite

```
which uwsgi
//anaconda/bin/uwsgi
```

, resulting in `No such file or directory`. Currently, I set `uWSGI="//anaconda/bin/uwsgi"` to get around the problem at and get uwsgi to work, but I suspect a similar problem may be occurring. I think it might be trying to use `/usr/bin/python` instead of `/anaconda/bin/python`, and it can't import from anaconda, resulting in the error. However, I'm not sure how to fix it/confirm that this is the problem, and any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT: I have also tried `import _io` using all of the current versions of python installed, and there was no problem. `brew unlink python` helped deal with the conflicting anaconda version for the `uwsgi` problem (initially fixed with alias, as above), but this issue still exists.

EDIT: Removing anaconda from $PATH, and then reinstalling/unlinking/linking django, openssl, and libxml2 "works". I'll find out if this causes problems in the later steps shortly, but I still have no idea what was happening with the anaconda install. I'd really like to figure out what's going on since I use scipy/numpy/etc. very frequently, so this is definitely a temporary fix. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you installing uWSGI via `pip install uwsgi` in for Anaconda Python compilation, not `/usr/bin/python` or `/usr/loacl/bin/uwsgi`?

Comment: I'm actually not sure which one I'm installing for (I just ran `pip install uwsgi`) though I'm pretty convinced it was for Anaconda as once installation was complete, it said to call it from `//anaconda/bin/uwsgi`. In addition, `pip show uwsgi` gives me `pip show uwsgi
---
Name: uWSGI
Version: 2.0.9
Location: /anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: `

Comment: Use virtualenv: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html#creating-virtual-environments

Comment: I couldn't quite get it working with a virtualenv when it tried to use anaconda. I'll look into it more though. Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34167557/uwsgi-fails-under-pyenv-2-7-11-with-io-so-undefined-symbol-pycodecinfo-getin/34168578#34168578

Answer (score 3):

I just encountered this issue trying to run `uwsgi` on my mac with my django project

`uwsgi --http :9090 --module uwsgi_django_project.wsgi`

(in this case my django project was named `uwsgi_django_project`)

The stack-trace from uwsgi was

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./uwsgi_django_project/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/django_uwsgi_39/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.utils.version import get_version
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/django_uwsgi_39/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/version.py", line 1, in <module>
    import datetime
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/django_uwsgi_39/lib/python3.8/datetime.py", line 8, in <module>
    import math as _math
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/anaconda3/envs/django_uwsgi_39/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/math.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyExc_MemoryError
  Referenced from: /opt/anaconda3/envs/django_uwsgi_39/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/math.cpython-38-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /opt/anaconda3/envs/django_uwsgi_39/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/math.cpython-38-darwin.so
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
```

Very similar to the error OP was getting except `Symbol not found: _PyExc_MemoryError` instead.

I had installed `uwsgi` via pip inside my conda environment and apparently there is an incompatability between the package installed via pip and the anaconda environment's python.

The solution was to remove `uwsgi` from my environment

`pip uninstall uwsgi`

and install it using anaconda

`conda install -c conda-forge uwsgi`

after doing this and running uwsgi with my django app it worked fine.

Credit to this [blog](https://jdhao.github.io/2020/07/02/uwsgi_install_use_issue/#symbol-not-found-on-macos) where I found the solution to my issue which probably would solve a lot of similar issues with `uwsgi` and `django`