# uwsgi fails under pyenv/2.7.11 with _io.so: undefined symbol: _PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalEncoder

Tags: python, uwsgi, pyenv

when i start uwsgi 2.0.11.2 under pyenv 2.7.11 i get:

ImportError: /home/user/.pyenv/versions/2.7.11/envs/master2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so: undefined symbol: _PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalEncoder

also uwsgi prints
Python version: 2.7.10 (default, May 30 2015, 13:57:08)  [GCC 4.8.2]

not sure how to fix it

Comment: What kind of settings do you use when starting the process. If you are using .ini file, do you have key 'home' defined?

Comment: there is nothing python version / path specific in the ini, when i run uwsgi from the project dir pyenv takes care of python path, it all worked for 2.7.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same (or better: a similar) problem with *uwsgi* when upgrading *Python* from *2.7.3* to *2.7.10*:

- The module that I tried to import was *socket* (*socket.py*)

  - Which in turn tried to import *_socket* (*_socket.so*) - and the unresolved symbol was `_PyInt_AsInt`

The problem is a mismatch between some functions between *Python* **minor minor** releases (which doesn't break any backward compatibility, *BTW*). Let me detail:

- Build time: when your *uwsgi* was built, the build was against *Python 2.7.10*
  (as you specified). *Python* could have been compiled/built:

  - statically - most likely, the *PYTHON LIBRARY* (from now on, I am going to refer to it as ***PYTHONCORE*** as it's named by its creators) in this case: (*libpython2.7.a*) is in a static lib which is included in the *python* executable resulting a huge ~6MB executable
  - dynamically - ***PYTHONCORE*** (*libpython2.7.so*) is a dynamic library which *python* executable (~10KB of bytes large, this time) uses at runtime
- Run time: the above *uwsgi* must run in an *Python 2.7.11* environment

Regardless of how *Python* is compiled, the following thing happened: between *2.7.10* and *2.7.11* some internal functions were added/removed (in our case added) from both:

- ***PYTHONCORE***
- Dynamic (or extension) modules (written in *C*) - *.so* files located in *${PYTHON_LIB_DIR}/lib-dynload* (e.g. */home/user/.pyenv/versions/2.7.11/envs/master2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload*); any dynamic module (*.so*) is a client for ***PYTHONCORE***

So, basically it's a version mismatch (encountered at runtime):

- *2.7.10* (which *uwsgi* was compiled against):

  - ***PYTHONCORE*** - doesn't export `PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalEncoder`
  - *_io.so* (obviously) doesn't use the exported func (so, no complains at *import* time)
- *2.7.11* (which *uwsgi* is run against):

  - ***PYTHONCORE*** - **still** (as it was "embedded" in *uwsgi* at compile (build) time, so it's still *2.7.10*) doesn't export `PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalEncoder`
  - *_io.so* - uses/needs it

resulting a situation where a *Python 2.7.11* dynamic module was used against *Python 2.7.10* runtime, which is unsupported.

As a conclusion make sure that your *uwsgi* buildmachine is in sync (from *Python* *PoV*) with the *runmachine*, or - in other words - **build *uwsgi* with the same *Python* version you intend to run it with!**

Answer (score 2):

CristiFati covered the why part. The exact how to for me was:

```
cd my_pyenv_virtualenv
wget http://projects.unbit.it/downloads/uwsgi-latest.tar.gz
tar xf uwsgi-latest.tar.gz
cd uwsgi-2.0.11.2
python uwsgiconfig.py --build
mv uwsgi /home/user/.pyenv/versions/2.7.11/envs/master2/bin/uwsgi
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on RHEL, and eventually discovered it was due to the tsch shell I was using. I solved the problem by switching to the bash shell:

```
bash
```

which allowed my script to run fine.